# find any number from 6 equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

suppose i have six equations which are equal to different numerical values.

x + y = A(numerical value)

x + d = B(numerical value)

y - d = C(numerical value)

a + b = D(numerical value)

a + d = E(numerical value)

b - d = F(numerical value)

Find any one of them. i mean  x (or) y (or) a (or) b (or) d

i gone through several logics. but due to limited knowledge in mathematics i am not able to find a solution for this.

Please! you will be really appreciated.

ex:

```
x+y = 502

x+d = 473

y-d = 29

a+b = 437

a+d = 460

b-d = -23
```

find any one of them(x,y,d,a,b)

Comment: I suggest looking into some (very introductory) Linear Algebra if you're going to be solving many systems of equations like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit deceiving, because in fact what you have here is $4$ independent equations and $5$ variables, so there are either infinitely many solutions or no solutions.  Notice that adding the second and third equations gives you the first equation, and similarly the fifth and sixth sum to the fourth.

Here is one possible solution: $(x,y,d,a,b)=(0,502,473,-13,450)$.  This means there must be infinitely many more.

Comment: suppose x+d and y-d is one group.   a+d and b-d is another group. now i want to find if  "d"  is constant number in these two groups. like true/false.  please guide me what to do in this case.

Comment: @VaibhavChiruguri: Yes, if you set $d$ equal to any constant, then the values for $x,y,a,$ and $b$ will follow from the equations you have listed.  This is an easy way to generate solutions.

Comment: actually we dont know value of d. i just want to check if d is constant in those two groups.

Comment: @VaibhavChiruguri: Since there are infinitely many solutions, $d$ can have any value.  Then the values of $a,b,x,$ and $y$ will be determined after that.  So in a particular solution, yes $d$ will be constant, it must be.  However, there is not one constant value of $d$ that gives all solutions.  In 'those two groups' you still have $3$ variables and $2$ equations, or $5$ variables and $4$ equations, depending on how you count.  When you have more variables than equations, there will never be a unique solution.

Comment: Just to expand slightly on **Jared**'s comments (and relate it to your original post):  it is a little easier to see this if you've worked with matrices, but your equations essentially reduce to $ \ x + y = A \ , \ a + b = D \ , \ $ and $ \ y - b =  C - F \ $ .  So the variables $ \ x \ $ and $ \ y \ $ are really only connected with $ \ a \ $ and $ \ b \ $  through the relation between $ \ y \ $ and $ \ b \ $ .  That leaves a _whole lot_ of freedom for possible solutions to your set of equations.  (Indeed, since $ \ d \ $ "drops out" of the solution, you can call it anything you wish!)

Answer (score 0):

pick $x$

$$y = A-x$$
$$d = B-x$$
$$a = E-B+x$$
$$d = D-E+B-x$$
As several people have stated, there are an infinite number of answers as you have an infinite number of options for $x$.